# How to write security rules in cloud fire store for read if I want my users to read all news and updates from my application without sign in?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

My application is a local news application that publishes the news and happenings of my village and nearby surroundings. I want people to read all the news without any authentication and only the app owner or publisher can write the news. So, in this case, I have the following  rules:

```
allow read: if true;
allow write: if request.auth.uid =="My uid"
```

But when I do this I get this message in my email from Firestore:

Your Cloud Firestore database has insecure rules.
We've detected the following issue(s) with your security rules:
any user can read your entire database

Answer (score 3):

You're not showing the entire rules, but if they look like this:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid =="My uid"
    }
  }
}
```

Firestore finds that to be insecure because you are applying universal read access to every single document in the entire database.  This can lead to unexpected security problems.

Instead, you should call out individual collections that should have read and write access.  Don't use the wildcard `/{document=**}`.

```
    match /collection-name/{id} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid =="My uid"
    }
```

I suggest reading the [documentation on security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) thoroughly (not just the first page) to learn how they work.

Comment: Oh, okay....thanks a lot. I was doing this for all the database instead of doing it for a particular collection.